# Multiple custom post loops on page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm unable to get a second or third loop to display after the first loop is displayed. I've been trying different things for the past two hours but I'm running out of ideas.

This is what I have right now --

```
<?php
$type = 'new_trucks';
$args=array(
 'orderby' => 'rand',
 'post_type' => $type,
 'paged' => $paged,
 'posts_per_page' => 3,
);

$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query($args);
?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
...
<?php endwhile; /* End loop */ ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The second loop is like so and is right under the first loop shown above...

```
<?php
$type = 'used_trucks';
$args=array(
 'orderby' => 'rand',
 'post_type' => $type,
 'paged' => $paged,
 'posts_per_page' => 3,
);

$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query($args);
?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
...
<?php endwhile; /* End loop */ ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

In my attempts to duplicate that in the same page with a different type set, the second loop is not displaying at all. If I erase the first loop, it works. I'm hoping someone can please provide some guidance.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Wayne,
I'm copying and pasting this loop throughout the page but changing $type -- I only pasted it once here because I didn't want to clutter the code view with the same code 3 times over.

Comment: What output are you actually getting?

Comment: Basically the first loop is showing properly but the second one is not showing at all (no error, or any content at all.. just the surrounding HTML).

I just updated the original post with the second loop I'm using (in the same page as the first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$type = 'new_trucks';
$args=array(
 'orderby' => 'rand',
 'post_type' => $type,
 'paged' => $paged,
 'posts_per_page' => 3,
);

$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

?>

<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
...
<?php endwhile; /* End loop */ ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

is how I have done it in the past

Comment: Using this the first loop appears correctly but the second loop does not show properly.

Comment: does it work if you remove the 'paged' and 'posts_per_page' from the args? wordpress often displays odd behaviour when using those arguments, especially when posts_per_page is different from the setting in wp-admin. Also if you are using orderby rand and having pagination there is a chance of duplicate content on every page as the content of the pages is not consistent.